# Terminal mac (bash) script to extract, move and clean a WordPress install

Tags: macos, bash, ssh, terminal.app

I want to be able to copy/paste into terminal;

```
wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
tar -xzvf latest.tar.gz
mv wordpress/* .
rmdir wordpress
rm latest.tar.gz
```

But I want correct wait commands in there so it doesn't try to move the wordpress directory before it's finished extracting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any "wait" command, it's fine as it is. Your tar command is not being backgrounded, so the script has no choice but to wait for it to finish before executing the next command.

Take a look at this thread for example: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26506/wait-for-process-to-finish-before-going-to-the-next-line-in-shell-script